# Change value of a nested key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to change an specific value in a nested key value structure, but when I set a value it changes all key's value.

Initial data is:

```py
   const data = {
      "1.157685561": {
        "1222344": {
          "batb": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ],
          "batl": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ]
        },
        "1222345": {
          "batb": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ],
          "batl": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to change the value of an specific path

```py
    data['1.157685561']['1222344']['batl'][0] = [1,2]
```

But the result is wrong. Because it changes:

- `data['1.157685561']['1222344']`
- `data['1.157685561']['1222345']`

Final result:

```
    {
      "1.157685561": {
        "1222344": {
          "batb": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ],
          "batl": [
            [1, 2],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ]
        },
        "1222345": {
          "batb": [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ],
          "batl": [
            [1, 2],
            [0, 0],
            [0, 0]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Source code: https://playcode.io/301552?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: How would that occur? You must have some other code you're not showing us - that literally would not happen.

Comment: How did you generate that structure?

Comment: I guess that you are you didn't copied the object. So they keep the reference. Can you create a runnable snippet to show the problem?

Comment: I did add the source code

Comment: @Shidersz  So what is problem changing it to `[1, 2]`

Comment: Sorry, guys. I've updated the source code.

Comment: Check this line: `for (const runner of runners) {data[runner] = marketData;}`. Since `marketData` is an `object`, you are storing multiple references to the same `object`. That is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this section of the [provided code](https://playcode.io/301552?tabs=console&script.js&output):

```
function createEmptyMarketData(runners) {
    const data = {};
    const marketData = {
        batb: [
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0]
        ],
        batl: [
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0]
        ]
    };

    for (const runner of runners) {
        data[runner] = marketData;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Using `for (const runner of runners) {data[runner] = marketData;}` you are storing multiple references to the same object. That is a problem.

One possible solution is to change `marketData` to a method that generate a new `object` every time is called. Example:

```
function createEmptyMarketData(runners)
{
    const data = {};

    const marketData = () => ({
        batb: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
        batl: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
    });

    for (const runner of runners)
    {
        data[runner] = marketData();
    }

    return data;
}
```

**New version:** https://playcode.io/301583?tabs=console&script.js&output

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, @Shidersz is right. I also checked because when I tried from the Node terminal, I couldn't see any issue as the object you have pasted in the problem is the one created by function (So it works fine).

```
> const data = {
...       "1.157685561": {
.....         "1222344": {
.......           "batb": [
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0]
.......           ],
.......           "batl": [
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0]
.......           ]
.......         },
.....         "1222345": {
.......           "batb": [
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0]
.......           ],
.......           "batl": [
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0],
.......             [0, 0]
.......           ]
.......         }
.....       }
...     }
undefined
> 
> data['1.157685561']['1222344']['batl'][0] = [1,2]
[ 1, 2 ]
> 
> data
{ '1.157685561':
   { '1222344': { batb: [Array], batl: [Array] },
     '1222345': { batb: [Array], batl: [Array] } } }
> 
> data['1.157685561']['1222344']['batl'][0]
[ 1, 2 ]
> 
> data['1.157685561']['1222345']['batl'][0]
[ 0, 0 ]
>
```

I thought, what is happening then. Finally, I checked your code which is creating **data**. There you're referencing the same object for different keys.

So, updating a single one is like affecting others but internally they are just references to a same memory location where the real object is stored.

> This [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) would be really very very helpful for you to understand the concept of Deep & Shallow copy of variables.

Finally you can check the updated code at https://playcode.io/301586?tabs=console&script.js&output. I have just copied the outer **marketData** and placed inside for loop.

That is it. Thank you v. much.